# Import Foreign Type with postgresql_fdw

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

I have a database with a custom type which could not import using the `IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public FROM SERVER replica_db1 INTO db1` since `CREATE FOREIGN TABLE` fails.  How do I import custom type?  Also, the custom type is referred from the public schema, how do I change it to use schema from local server?

```
reporting=> IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public FROM SERVER replica_db1 INTO db1;
ERROR:  type "public.custom_type" does not exist
LINE 8:   start public.custom_type OPTIONS (column_name 'start'),
                ^
QUERY:  CREATE FOREIGN TABLE table1 (
  id bigint OPTIONS (column_name 'id') NOT NULL,
  start public.custom_type OPTIONS (column_name 'start'),
  "end" public.custom_type OPTIONS (column_name 'end')
) SERVER replica_db1
OPTIONS (schema_name 'public', table_name 'table1');
CONTEXT:  importing foreign table "table1"
reporting=> IMPORT FOREIGN TYPE public FROM SERVER replica_db1 INTO db1;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TYPE"
LINE 1: IMPORT FOREIGN TYPE public FROM SERVER replica_db1 INT...
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there any solution right now? I find manually copy type boring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must create the  data type "public.custom_type" in your server before import the schema with the command:

```
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public FROM SERVER replica_db1 INTO db1;
```

Comment: Yes, I created the custom_type as a workaround to resolve this issue.  I am trying to find out is there any built-in feature that can automatically create the foreign type.

Comment: As I browsed various sources, there is not such feature. PG authors seem reluctant to solve any relation dependencies in `import foreign schema` implementation. See this interesting thread: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20141203213139.GA9855%40fetter.org